# C dynamic strings

Tags: c, strings

In the process of writing a compiler, I wrote this dynamic string library to help with keeping track of heap allocated strings and to have an easy way to format them.

**Note:**
The macros `ALLOC()`, `CALLOC()`, and `REALLOC()` used in the implementation are equivalent to the C stdlib functions `malloc()`, `calloc()`, and `realloc()`. They expand to the memory allocator used in the compiler that also does `NULL` checking, that is why the implementation doesn't check for `NULL` after allocating.
They are declared in the header `memory.h`.

**Interface (Strings.h):**

```c
#ifndef STRINGS_H
#define STRINGS_H

#include <stddef.h> // size_t
#include <stdbool.h>

// NOTES
// =====
// The 'String' type is equivalent to a C string ('char *'), and therefore can
// be used with the regular C string functions.
// In this API, the String type is used when a string created by this library is expected,
// and 'char *' is used when both types can be used.
// 'const char *' is used when ONLY C strings are expected.

typedef char *String;

/***
 * Create a new empty string 'length' long
 * NOTE: strings returned by stringNew() can ONLY be freed with stringFree()
 *
 * @param length The length of the new string.
 * @return A pointer to a new heap allocated string.
 ***/
String stringNew(size_t length);

/***
 * Free a string created by stringNew() or stringCopy();
 *
 * @param s A string created with stringNew() or stringCopy().
 ***/
void stringFree(String s);

/***
 * Check if a string was created by stringNew(), stringCopy(), or stringDuplicate().
 *
 * @param s A string.
 * @return true if valid, false if not.
 ***/
bool stringIsValid(String s);

/***
 * Return the length of a string allocated with stringNew() or stringCopy().
 * 
 * @param s A string allocated by stringNew() or stringCopy().
 * @return The length of the string.
 ***/
size_t stringLength(String s);

/***
 * Resize a string allocated by stringNew() or stringCopy().
 * NOTE: if 'newSize' is smaller than the current length, data will be lost!
 *
 * @param s A string allocated by stringNew() or stringCopy().
 * @param newLength The new length. can't be 0.
 * @return A new string of length 'newLength'.
 ***/
String stringResize(String s, size_t newLength);

/***
 * Copy 'length' characters from 's' into a new string.
 *
 * @param s A string to copy.
 * @param length How much characters to copy.
 * @return A new copy of 'length' characters of 's'.
 ***/
String stringNCopy(const char *s, int length);

/***
 * Copy a string into a new string.
 *
 * @param s A string to copy.
 * @return A new copy of the string.
 ***/
String stringCopy(const char *s);

/***
 * Duplicate a string allocated with stringNew() or stringCopy().
 *
 * @param s A string allocated by stringNew() or stringCopy().
 * @return A new copy of the string.
 ***/
String stringDuplicate(String s);

/***
 * Check if 2 strings are equal.
 * The strings can be regular C strings as well.
 *
 * @param s1 A string
 * @param s2 Another string
 * @return true if equal, false if not
 ***/
bool stringEqual(char *s1, char *s2);

/***
 * Format a string (using printf-like format specifiers) and return it.
 * 
 * @param format The format string.
 * @return A new String containing the formatted format string.
 ***/
String stringFormat(const char *format, ...);

/***
 * Append format to dest (printf-like formatting supported)
 * NOTE: the string might be reallocated.
 *
 * @param dest the destination string.
 * @param format the string to append (printf-like format specifiers supported).
 ***/
void stringAppend(String *dest, const char *format, ...);

#endif // STRINGS_H
```

**Implementation (Strings.c):**

````c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // memcpy(), memset()
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "memory.h"
#include "Strings.h"

// C = capacity
// L = length
// M = magic number
// D = data
// ________________________
// |   |   |   |   |   |   | ...
// | C | L | M | D | D | D | ...
// |___|___|___|___|___|___| ...
//

enum slots {
    CAPACITY   = 0,
    LENGTH     = 1,
    MAGIC      = 2,
    SLOT_COUNT = 3
};

static inline size_t *from_str(char *s) {
    return ((size_t *)s) - SLOT_COUNT;
}

static inline char *to_str(size_t *ptr) {
    return (char *)(ptr + SLOT_COUNT);
}

String stringNew(size_t capacity) {
    assert(capacity > 0);
    size_t *ptr = CALLOC(sizeof(size_t) * SLOT_COUNT + sizeof(char) * (capacity + 1));
    ptr[CAPACITY] = capacity + 1; // capacity
    ptr[LENGTH] = 0; // length
    ptr[MAGIC] = 0xDEADC0DE; // magic
    return to_str(ptr);
}

void stringFree(String s) {
    assert(stringIsValid(s));
    // Remove the magic number in case the string is used again accidentally.
    from_str(s)[MAGIC] = 0;
    FREE(from_str(s));
}

bool stringIsValid(String s) {
    return from_str(s)[MAGIC] == 0xDEADC0DE;
}

size_t stringLength(String s) {
    return from_str(s)[LENGTH];
}

String stringResize(String s, size_t newCapacity) {
    assert(newCapacity > 0);
    size_t *ptr = from_str(s);
    size_t oldCap = ptr[CAPACITY];
    ptr = REALLOC(ptr, newCapacity);
    memset(to_str(ptr) + oldCap, 0, labs(((ssize_t)oldCap) - ((ssize_t)newCapacity)));
    ptr[CAPACITY] = newCapacity;
    return to_str(ptr);
}

String stringNCopy(const char *s, int length) {
    String str = stringNew(length);
    memcpy(str, s, length);
    from_str(str)[LENGTH] = length;
    return str;
}

String stringCopy(const char *s) {
    return stringNCopy(s, strlen(s));
}

String stringDuplicate(String s) {
    assert(stringIsValid(s));
    return stringNCopy((const char *)s, stringLength(s));
}

bool stringEqual(char *s1, char *s2) {
    size_t length1, length2;
    if(stringIsValid(s1)) {
        length1 = stringLength(s1);
    } else {
        length1 = strlen(s1);
    }
    if(stringIsValid(s2)) {
        length2 = stringLength(s2);
    } else {
        length2 = strlen(s2);
    }

    if(length1 != length2) {
        return false;
    }
    return memcmp(s1, s2, length1) == 0;
}

static String vformat(const char *format, va_list ap) {
    va_list copy;
    va_copy(copy, ap);
    // Get the total length of the formatted string.
    // see man 3 printf.
    int needed_length = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, copy);
    va_end(copy);

    String s = stringNew(needed_length + 1);
    vsnprintf(s, needed_length + 1, format, ap);
    from_str(s)[LENGTH] = needed_length;
    return s;
}

String stringFormat(const char *format, ...) {
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, format);
    String s = vformat(format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return s;
}

void stringAppend(String *dest, const char *format, ...) {
    assert(stringIsValid(*dest));
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, format);
    String buffer = vformat(format, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    if((size_t)(stringLength(buffer) + 1) > from_str(*dest)[CAPACITY]) {
        *dest = stringResize(*dest, stringLength(*dest) + stringLength(buffer) + 1);
    }
    strncat(*dest, buffer, stringLength(buffer));
    // *dest is zeroed by stringNew() & stringResize(), so no need to terminate the string.
    from_str(*dest)[LENGTH] += stringLength(buffer);
    stringFree(buffer);
}
```
````

Comment: The code looks reasonable overall, but I think you lack good unit tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A word of warning. Writing yet another string library is a goo programming exercise, but if your goal is to write a compiler, concentrate on the compilation tasks (grammar, optimization , code generation..), and don't get sidetracked. Use c++; `std::string` offers everything you need out of the box.

That said,

- `typedef char *String;` means that the library accepts *any* `char *` as `String`. This is a ticket to disaster. Pass an unaligned `char *` to, say, `stringResize`, and enjoy an unaligned access exception on any arch but x86. Consider declaring

  ```
    typedef struct {
        size_t capacity;
        // etc
        ....
    } String;
  ```

  and let your library distinguish `String *` from `char *`.
- `MAGIC` is only used in `stringIsValid`, and most uses of `stringIsValid` are hidden behind `assert`. Recall that in the production code `assert` compiles to nothing, so it becomes a dead code indeed.

  The only non-assert use is in `stringEqual`, and it is much more dangerous. If the magic field is corrupted, God knows what `length1` and/or `lenght2` evaluate to.
- Using `strncat` in `stringAppend` is suboptimal. You already know where the buffer shall be copied to; there is no need to recompute this position.

Comment: I don't understand why it is dangerous using stringIsValid in stringEqual. all `String`s are null terminated unless manually changed, so `strlen` will give the correct size.